# IDE Fatal Error, Exception in plagin Flutter Snippets

Tags: android, flutter

IDE Fatal Error, Exception in plagin Flutter Snippets.How to solve and is it going to create any issue in project?

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot create extension (class=FlutterContext) [Plugin: com.gionchat]
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createError(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:931)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.createInstance(XmlExtensionAdapter.java:88)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapter(ExtensionPointImpl.java:489)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapters(ExtensionPointImpl.java:437)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.computeExtensionList(ExtensionPointImpl.java:249)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.getExtensionList(ExtensionPointImpl.java:243)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateContextTypes.getAllContextTypes(TemplateContextTypes.java:20)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateContext$1.compute(TemplateContext.java:51)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateContext$1.compute(TemplateContext.java:31)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClearableLazyValue.getValue(ClearableLazyValue.java:39)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateContext.readTemplateContext(TemplateContext.java:105)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateSettings.readTemplateFromElement(TemplateSettings.java:715)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateSettings.parseTemplateGroup(TemplateSettings.java:616)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateSettings.readDefTemplate(TemplateSettings.java:568)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateSettings.loadDefaultLiveTemplatesFromProvider(TemplateSettings.java:522)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateSettings.loadDefaultLiveTemplates(TemplateSettings.java:493)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateSettings.doLoadTemplates(TemplateSettings.java:300)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateSettings.(TemplateSettings.java:280)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateSettings.(TemplateSettings.java:192)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:47)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:876)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:47)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.access$createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:12)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter$doCreateInstance$1.compute(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:41)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:646)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeInNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:237)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:40)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:113)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:67)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:60)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:595)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:569)
at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.getFromSelfOrCurrentSession(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.getService(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:22)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.TemplateSettings.getInstance(TemplateSettings.java:304)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.LiveTemplatesOptionsTopHitProvider.getOptions(LiveTemplatesOptionsTopHitProvider.java:24)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.TopHitCache.lambda$getCachedOptions$0(TopHitCache.java:66)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.TopHitCache.getCachedOptions(TopHitCache.java:58)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider.getCachedOptions(OptionsTopHitProvider.java:52)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider$Activity.lambda$cacheAll$0(OptionsTopHitProvider.java:192)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointImpl.java:299)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointName.java:144)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider$Activity.cacheAll(OptionsTopHitProvider.java:188)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider$Activity.preload(OptionsTopHitProvider.java:176)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$executePreloadActivity$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:418)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:624)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:646)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:623)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.executePreloadActivity(ApplicationLoader.kt:408)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$executePreloadActivity(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$executePreloadActivities$2.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:473)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FlutterContext PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Flutter Snippets, id=com.gionchat, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3/FlutterSnippets.jar, version=1.3.4, package=null, isBundled=false), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=51, state=active)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImplKt.doLoadClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:1443)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImplKt.access$doLoadClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:1)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.loadClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:821)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.InterfaceExtensionImplementationClassResolver.resolveImplementationClass(InterfaceExtensionImplementationClassResolver.java:25)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.createInstance(XmlExtensionAdapter.java:65)
... 63 more

no idea about the problem..how to solve this?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).